# Create login UI identical to iPhone UI using XML

Tags: android, xml

I have the following screenshot from an iPhone app of a login-password textbox. I was wondering if anyone knows how to recreate the exact thing on android (specifically the login textbox stacked on top of password textbox with the corners rounded and borders set).

[image]

Comment: *Don't ask about...

**1. Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)**
2. Product or service recommendations or comparisons
3. Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.
4. Anything not directly related to writing computer programs* [source](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [9-patch images](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) for the background. That way you can have both rounded corners and regular corners. The stacking can be achieved by removing paddingBottom and paddingTop respectively from the two EditText boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, 9patch as a background is the most obvious way.
Now concerning the second question: actually there is no "stacking" itself, like you said. If you scrutinize this UI, you'll find, that it's just a simple LinearLayout with delimeters. You can add your EditTexts there, play with paddings. FYI, `android:includeFontPadding="false"` XML attribute may be helpful (and see some others at [this post](http://radleymarx.com/blog/15-quirky-android-xml-layout-parameters-to-know/))